# How do i arranged and fill the missing fields from reading two files in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have two text files

cat A.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"ABC"
```

cat B.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,4,"bokaj"
```

I want to find the missing fields by reading from two text files and fill up  in both the files for missing fields by "  " and save to two new modified files How do i get this say

A1.txt is a modified version of A.txt

cat A1.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"ABC"
10,2,4,"  "
```

B1.txt is a modified version of B.txt

cat B1.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"  "
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"  "
10,2,4,"bokaj"
```

make sure that total number of lines in A1.txt is same as that of B1.txt,sorry i was not able to post my MWE as due to lack of commands as i am new to bash, your answer with explaination may help me to learn this.

This is my MWE which i tried so far

```
#!/bin/bash


cut -d ',' -f1,2,3 A.txt > A1.txt
cut -d ',' -f1,2,3 B.txt > B1.txt


## Command to print contents which are in B1.txt but not in A1.txt

A=`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' A1.txt B1.txt`
echo $A,'" "' >> A.txt
sort A.txt

## Command to print contents which are in A1.txt but not in B1.txt

B=`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' B1.txt A1.txt`
echo $B,'" "' >> B.txt
sort B.txt
```

Comment: `cut` first 3 fields from both files -> `sort` both files -> `comm -12` -> append the last field `sed 's/$/,"   "/'` -> append to the destination file -> re`sort` sort destination file

Comment: Yes you right but because lack of commands i was not able to post my MWE for that one as i am new to bash. @ScottHunter

Comment: Och, found it, [here's a good read](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: You'll kill  yourself trying to debug a problem with a files named `A'.txt` and `B'.txt`. The single-quote is a crucial part of shell syntax and will blow up your code, with only the hardest to understand error messages. Better to use `A_alt.txt` or something that just uses alpha chars. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting as i am new to shell scripting, but i want to learn @shellter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

- first extract the comparable part of the files - ie. first 3 fields
- then sort them to extract the unique lines in the files
- add the the unique lines from both files the suffix `,"  "`
- print the unique lines from the A.txt file with B.txt file, sort it and put into B1.txt file
- print the unique lines from the B.txt file with A.txt file, sort it and put it into A1.txt file

The following code:

```
cat <<EOF >A.txt
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"ABC"
EOF
cat <<EOF >B.txt
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,4,"bokaj"
EOF

# extract unique lines from first and second file
# hide lines common in both files
comm -3 <(
  # extract 3 fields from A.txt and sort
  < A.txt \
  cut -d, -f1-3 |
  sort
) <(
  # extract 3 fields from B.txt and sort
  < B.txt \
  cut -d, -f1-3 |
  sort
) |
# suffix with `,"   "` string
sed 's/$/,"  "/' |
# split the stream
tee >(
  # extract lines unique to the first file, ie. A.txt file
  grep -v $'^\t' |
  # join the stream with the content of B.txt file
  # also note that lines from stdin are preferred in sorting order
  # over the same lines from B.txt file
  # sort it using first 3 fields. Preserve sorting from B.txt file
  # and put the output into B1.txt
  sort -s -t, -k1,3 - B.txt \
  > B1.txt
) |
# extract lines unique to the second file, ie. B.txt file
grep $'^\t' | cut -f2 |
# join the output with A.txt file
# sort it using first 3 fields, preserve sorting, put into A1.txt
sort -s -t, -k1,3 - A.txt \
> A1.txt

# verbose output
set -x
cat B1.txt
cat A1.txt
```

will output:

```
++ cat B1.txt
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"  "
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"  "
10,2,4,"bokaj"
++ cat A1.txt
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,3,"ABC"
10,2,4,"  "
```

tested on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FearfulOutstandingElement).

`comm` has a strange output, as it doesn't suffix with the delimete lines unique to the first file. So I learned to `grep` the tabulation to extract unique lines, so to get unique lines from A.txt or B.txt files I do `grep -v $'^\t'` or `grep $'^\t' | cut -d2` respectively.

When running `comm` two times, this script could be more verbose and more "linear like" (don't know how to call it, without `tee`):

```
comm -13 <(
  < A.txt \
  cut -d, -f1-3 |
  sort
) <(
  < B.txt \
  cut -d, -f1-3 |
  sort
) |
sed 's/$/,"  "/' |
sort -s -t, -k1,3 - A.txt \
> A1.txt

comm -23 <(
  < A.txt \
  cut -d, -f1-3 |
  sort
) <(
  < B.txt \
  cut -d, -f1-3 |
  sort
) |
sed 's/$/,"  "/' |
sort -s -t, -k1,3 - B.txt \
> B1.txt
```

And some neat 4 liner:

```
comm -3 <(cut -d, -f1-3 A.txt | sort) <(cut -d, -f1-3 B.txt | sort) |
sed 's/$/,"  "/' |
tee >(grep -v $'^\t'  | sort -s -t, -k1,3 - B.txt > B1.txt) |
grep $'^\t' | cut -f2 | sort -s -t, -k1,3 - A.txt > A1.txt
```

Comment: For larger no. Of lines it fails to sort for B.txt, insertion is working fine, only sorting is the problem @Kamil Cuk

Comment: You'd need to add `n` to each sort field for numeric sorting and you'll need GNU sort for `-s`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` script that can do the task.

`script.awk`

```
FNR == NR {        # read first input file
    fileNames[1] = FILENAME".1";
    lines[FNR",1"] = $0;
    file1[$0];
    file1count = FNR;
    next;
}
{                  # read scond input file
    fileNames[2] = FILENAME".1"; 
    lines[FNR",2"] = $0;
    file2[$0];
}
END {
    printf "" > fileNames[1]; # clean file 1
    printf "" > fileNames[2]; # clean file 2
    maxFileLen = file1count > FNR ? file1count : FNR;
    for (i = 1; i <= maxFileLen; i++) {  # for each line in file 1
        print lines[i",1"] >> fileNames[1]; # overwrite file 1
        if (lines[i",1"] in file2 == 0) print replaceField(lines[i",1"]) >> fileNames[2];
        if (lines[i",2"] in file1 == 0) print replaceField(lines[i",2"]) >> fileNames[1];
        print lines[i",2"] >> fileNames[2]; # overwrite file 2
    }
}
function replaceField(inpStr) {
    sub(/"[^"]+"/, "\"     \"", inpStr);
    return inpStr;
}
```

running script

```
 awk -f script.awk A.txt B.txt
```

Output files append `.1` to file name

Output `A.txt.1`

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,1,"     "
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,4,"     "
10,2,3,"ABC"
```

Output `B.txt.1`

```
10,1,1,"     "
10,1,1,"ABC1"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"     "
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
10,2,4,"bokaj"
10,2,3,"     "
```

The output match the problem description. But not the sample output.

[image]

Comment: Not working  and not filling the missing line by " " @Dudi Boy

Comment: it was tested with the sample input you provided. Please provide sample where it fails.

Comment: Two input files are A.txt and B.txt, Output is the A1.txt and B1.txt you can see my post @Dudi Boy

Comment: Fixed to your request. Apparently misunderstanding in the task.

Comment: Your output is not matching to my requirement A1.txt and B1.txt values@Dudi Boy

Comment: That is because in `A.txt` first row is `10,1,1,"ABC"` and `B.txt` first row is `10,1,1,"ABC1"` . There are different.

Comment: I will post in the answer a side by side picture.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays, sorted_in, gensub(), and ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ keySet[$1][$2][$3] = key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 }
ARGIND==1 {
    instNr = ++tots[key]
}
ARGIND==2 {
    instNr = ++cnt2[key]
    if (instNr > tots[key]) {
        tots[key] = instNr
    }
}
{ vals[ARGIND,key,instNr] = $NF }

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (k1 in keySet) {
        for (k2 in keySet[k1]) {
            for (k3 in keySet[k1][k2]) {
                keys[++numKeys] = keySet[k1][k2][k3]
            }
        }
    }

    prt(1)
    prt(2)
}

function prt(fileNr,    fname, keyNr, key, instNr, idx, val) {
    fname = gensub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",1,ARGV[fileNr]) "1.txt"
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        for (instNr=1; instNr<=tots[key]; instNr++) {
            idx = fileNr SUBSEP key SUBSEP instNr
            if ( !(idx in vals) ) {
                print key, "\"  \"" "\t> " fname
            }
        }
        for (instNr=1; instNr<=tots[key]; instNr++) {
            idx = fileNr SUBSEP key SUBSEP instNr
            if ( idx in vals ) {
                print key, vals[idx] "\t> " fname
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk A.txt B.txt
10,1,1,"ABC"    > A1.txt
10,1,2,"S1"     > A1.txt
10,1,2,"ABC"    > A1.txt
10,1,3,"baba"   > A1.txt
10,2,1,"S2"     > A1.txt
10,2,1,"asd"    > A1.txt
10,2,2,"S3"     > A1.txt
10,2,2,"dkkd"   > A1.txt
10,2,3,"ABC"    > A1.txt
10,2,4,"  "     > A1.txt
10,1,1,"ABC1"   > B1.txt
10,1,2,"S1"     > B1.txt
10,1,2,"ABC"    > B1.txt
10,1,3,"baba"   > B1.txt
10,2,1,"  "     > B1.txt
10,2,1,"asd"    > B1.txt
10,2,2,"S3"     > B1.txt
10,2,2,"dkkd"   > B1.txt
10,2,3,"  "     > B1.txt
10,2,4,"bokaj"  > B1.txt
```

Change `"\t> "` on the `print` line to just `>` when you're happy with the results to actually write to the output files.

Comment: sequence should be for B1.txt as 10,2,1, " " then 10,2,1,"asd" @Ed Morton

Comment: OK I tweaked it to implement one possible algorithm for why that might be the desired output (i.e. that all nulls come before all values for a given key). There's probably a more efficient way to do it without 2 loops on all instances of all keys within `prt()` but life's too short.